# can't make mod_rewrite regular expression quantifier to work

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello I have simple `RewriteRule ^news/([.+])/ /?pt-news=$1`, I want to exclude simple numbers with length not more 3 symbols, they work as paging navigation system in my site. So I need to send to `?pr-news=` everything what is not 3 digit number or 3 symbols set of characters. As far as I know that should be by something like `^news/([.+]{3})/ /?pt-news=$1` but I can't understand when to put quantifier so it could work, whatever I try fails. I need this rule not to work URI such as `/news/2/` or `/news/400/`. Please help.

Comment: Thanks but it does not work.

Comment: I need to work on something like `/news/hey-that-is-news/` or `/news/121220016` but it should not work when uri is like `/news/2/` or '/news/444/' when I have 1-3 digits number after `/news/` it is pagination, everything else is a page slug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exclude 1-3 digit numbers you can use negative lookahead:

```
RewriteRule ^news/((?!\d{1,3}/?$).+)/?$ /?pt-news=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Also I suggest you add some example URLs that you want to exclude from this rule.

Comment: Thank you that is what I was trying to do for 1.5 hours

Comment: All other rules are done by wordpress, I could not make it work with custom posts news without changing .htaccess. It is not the most elegant solution but it works.

Comment: I marked as solved, excuse me, I thought if I vote for that answer it will be automatically marked as 'solved', excuse me for delay.